# How to draw a thought bubble in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a thought bubble in iOS and want to fill it with image. I have gone through lots of results returned by internet search engines, but I did not get any solution.

The bubble, I want to create will be like the attached image below.

[image]

Comment: You wanna mask the image ?

Comment: Yes, I want to fill an image to a bubble like this, as it will be like a bubble containing the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to mask the image in the bubble. 
So make the bubble internally full black.(To use for masking) and use the bellow function for masking.

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
```

}

for more sample tutorial visit the following links :-)

http://jeroendeleeuw.com/post/33638733049/how-to-mask-images-with-core-graphics-in-ios

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create the inside of the bubble transparent, then create a `UIImageView` with it and add the image you want inside as a subview of it.

If you set `clipToBounds` property in the view to `YES`, the subview will stay inside the bubble!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how the image will take the shape of the bubble? As if I create a view, will take a rectangular or square shape.

Answer (score 0):

use a UIView and add two imageViews into it, one will contain the bubble and the other the image you want.make the uiview background color clearColor